# Getting value from textarea added via JS

Tags: javascript, html

Im not sure if im doing this right:

```
 <div>
    <form id="formPost" method="post">

    <div id="testdiv">
    </div>

    </form>
 </div>
 <div class="actions-left">
    <div id="textarea">
      <a href="javascript:ShowReplyTextArea();" class="button">Reply</a>
    </div>  
    <div id="postButton">
      <a href="javascript:ReplyPost(<%: Model.News.NewsId %>);" class="button">Post</a>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>

 <script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#postButton").hide();
 });

 function ShowReplyTextArea() {
   div = document.getElementById("testdiv")
   var textArea = document.createElement("textarea");
   textArea.rows = 10;
   textArea.cols = 10;
   textArea.id = "post_textarea";

   div.appendChild(textArea);

   if ($("#post_textarea").val() != null)
     $("#postButton").show();
 }

 function ReplyPost(newsId)
 {
   div = document.getElementById("testdiv")
   var textArea = document.createElement("textarea");
   div.appendChild(textArea);
   textArea.id = "reply_textarea";
   textArea.value = this.valueOf();;
   **var message = textArea.value.toString(); //problem here dont know how???
   alert(message);
   var jqxhr = $.getJSON("<%= Url.Action("ReplyPost", "Home", new { area = "News" }) %>?newsId=" + newsId + "&message=" + message, function (data) {**
   });
 }
</script>
```

then in my controller:

```
[HttpGet]
[NoCache]
public JsonResult ReplyPost(int newsId, string message)
{
  ZincService.NewsService.ReplyPost(newsId, message);
  return Json(new { success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

herewith the source:

```
  <div>
    <form id="formPost" method="post">

    <div id="testdiv">
    </div>

    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="actions-left">
    <div id="textarea">
      <a href="javascript:ShowReplyTextArea();" class="button">Reply</a>
    </div>  
    <div id="postButton">
      <a href="javascript:ReplyPost(116);" class="button">Post</a>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
```

how do i get the value of the text area so i can pass it on, the code i have there now is not correct, am i doing all of this correct?? i see no text area with my text i typed "sdfgsdfg"

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use :

```
var message = textArea.innerHTML;
```

Or

```
var message = textArea.innerText;
```

Or

```
var message = $(textArea).html();
```

Or

```
var message = $(textArea).text();
```

Comment: i tried them all and when i alert(message) they are all null im afraid :(

Comment: What does this mean? textArea.value = this.valueOf();;